# Why did Grimmel say, "No surprises"?

Tags: how-to-train-your-dragon

In *How to Train Your Dragon The Hidden World* (2019), a guard pokes his spear at Cloudjumper. 
Toothless roars out to him. Grimmel says:

> Um, that's right, alpha. **No surprises**.

Why did Grimmel say, "No surprises"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the script:

> (The dragons arrive at the Dragon Trapper ships. Cloudjumper lands on
>   a ship.)
>
> Dragon Trapper: Move! (Pokes Cloudjumper with a staff but Cloudjumper
>   roars at the trapper)
>
> (Toothless roars at Cloudjumper to stop him from getting angry.)
>
> Grimmel: Umm. That's right, Alpha. No surprises.
>
> (Toothless reluctantly growls at Cloudjumper, telling him to go into the cage. He goes into the cage and knocks two trappers over. Lots of dragons are also locked inside cages.)

Grimmel is telling Toothless to keep the dragons under control.